# PHP get URL value in mysql SELECT

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

in my current project I want to show statistics in a pie chart with chart.js, but they are different for each **team** on my page.

I tried to give the **WHERE** value in the Select in **playerOne.php** via the URL, but it doesn't seem to work because this PHP file is triggered by a JS function.
I have passed the team_id on the URL via isset get, but this doesn't seem to work.

How can I pass the team_id value on the URL to the query?

**playerOne.php**

```
    if(isset($_GET['team_id'])) {

        $team_id = $_GET['team_id'];
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE team_id = 7 LIMIT 1";
    $select_team = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_team);

    $user_id = $row['user_id'];

    $query = "SELECT SUM(game_stats.match_stats_kills) AS Kills, SUM(game_stats.match_stats_deaths) AS Deaths FROM game_stats WHERE game_stats.user_id = $user_id";
    $select_kd = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $data = array();
    foreach($select_kd as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);

    echo json_encode($data);
```

**stats.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showData();
});

function showData() {
{
    ($.post("includes/stats/playerOne.php",
    function(data) {

        var kills = [];
        var deaths = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            kills.push(data[i].Kills)
            deaths.push(data[i].Deaths);
        }

        var pieChartData = {
            labels: [
                'Kills', 'Deaths'
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00c0ef'],
                    data: [kills, deaths]
                }
            ]
        };

        var pieChartTarget = $('#playerKD').get(0).getContext('2d');

        var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartTarget, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: pieChartData
        });
    }));
}
}
```

**URL**

```
http://localhost/r6team/team/team.php?team=stats&team_id=7
```

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection; use a prepared statement. However, if the `team_id` will always be an integer, you can simply use `(int)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your JS, you need to send a GET request and leave room for the ID to be dynamic.
**stats.js** should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    showData(7);
});

function showData(teamId) {
{
    ($.get("includes/stats/playerOne.php?team_id=" + teamId,
    function(data) {

        var kills = [];
        var deaths = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            kills.push(data[i].Kills)
            deaths.push(data[i].Deaths);
        }

        var pieChartData = {
            labels: [
                'Kills', 'Deaths'
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00c0ef'],
                    data: [kills, deaths]
                }
            ]
        };

        var pieChartTarget = $('#playerKD').get(0).getContext('2d');

        var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartTarget, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: pieChartData
        });
    }));
  }
}
```

**playerOne.php** should then look like this:

```php
    $team_id = 0;//initialize team ID
    if(isset($_GET['team_id'])) {

        $team_id = $_GET['team_id'];
    }

    //double quotes are important so the $team_id variable will be interpreted to the value it holds
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE team_id = $team_id LIMIT 1";
    $select_team = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_team);

    $user_id = $row['user_id'];

    $query = "SELECT SUM(game_stats.match_stats_kills) AS Kills, SUM(game_stats.match_stats_deaths) AS Deaths FROM game_stats WHERE game_stats.user_id = $user_id";
    $select_kd = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $data = array();
    foreach($select_kd as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);

    echo json_encode($data);
```